# Converting Hive to spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a project which had hive scripts to process hadoop data on a daily basis.
I want to change hive to spark to process on hourly basis or live processing.
What is the best approach to convert hive scripts to spark?

Comment: This question is too wide, there are a lot of resources/blogs on the internet on how you can do it.  Try posting what research you have done before posting a question that will motivate people in the community to help you. #Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no conversion you need to do. Spark runs the exact same sql syntax as Hive. Or you can [make Hive run Spark executions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started)

Use Oozie or cron to schedule hourly intervals. Don't use Spark Streaming for this